# What function(s)/ API(s) are used when database configuration is exported/imported from "8002" port in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9, marklogic-7

Want to understand what function(s)/ API(s) are used when database configuration is exported/imported from `8002` port in `Marklogic`.
The purpose is to use these API(s) from `QConsole` to update `database configuration`.

There are different `admin APIs` to update individual configurations e.g. admin:database-set-one-character-searches, admin:database-set-three-character-word-positions - [admin database apis](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/admin/database) ; 
but I want a **single function/API** (if there is any) to update the `DB configuration` as in case of export/import from `8002` port where while importing `XML configuration` (which is exported from the same port) is passed and everything is configured in one go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The admin function API is granular for a reason. Also, it cannot be guaranteed you can make every needed change with just one QConsole script. Certain steps need to be finished before others can build atop, like you need to create roles before you can assign them to users. Other changes require server restart, like memory settings, and port changes.

Your best bet is the Configuration Management REST API, as described here:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/configuration-management-api

HTH!

Comment: `pkg:database-configuration` (deprecated MarkLogic 9 onward) can be used to export the database configuration.  `configuration management APIs` can also be used from QConsole - `cma:generate-config` and `cma:apply-config`; The `Configuration Management REST API` is equally helpful. Thanks.